# J2EE Outdated Design Patterns

Tags: jakarta-ee, design-patterns

I'm writing a paper for my master degree on JEE Design Patterns. I'm using with it the solutions that Spring gives us. 
I was searching for any info on the web but didn't got to much of info, probably someone with more experience would be of any help? If anyone could point me to any answers on this issue, I would be grateful.

Comment: Just wondering, why did you tag your question *obsolete*?

Comment: I intended to type 'obsolete design-patterns', but probably pressed space in between and didn't noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best book I have read about modern JEE Patterns is Real World Java EE Patterns-Rethinking Best Practices by Adam Bien. He is Java comitee member for EJB and JPA specs
http://adam-bien.com/

[Book](http://realworldpatterns.com/)

Comment: Hi, I stumbled on this one in the morning so will definitely check it out :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it does not perfectly answer your question, but it can be useful. Take a look at the [A Pattern Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Pattern_Language) book by Christopher Alexander. This book was one of the first books ever written about design patterns which had enormous influence on the software engineering as we seeing it today.

Comment: Hi Mikołaj, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately for me Mr. Alexander was and Architect, and this book that You mentioned has not much to do with no days patterns in Java ;). I based my master paper partly on the 'J2EE Core Patterns' and I'm tiring to search for patterns that where mentioned in there and are no longer used for (i.e. technical reasons). I think Session Facade (in terms of DAO) is one of them, but I'm not 100% sure.